# Can I say $7\mid 8(8^{t} - 1) + 14t + 49$?

Tags: combinatorics, induction

I'm working on some induction proofs as a homework assignment from Miklos Bona's book "A Walk Through Combinatorics."

I was asked to prove using induction that $$7\mid 8^{n} + 14n + 27$$ is true for all $\forall n \in \mathbb N$. I said let $P$ be my truth set.

I showed the base case $n = 1$ works, thus $1 \in P$. Then for my induction hypothesis I said let $n = k$ such that $7\mid 8^{k} + 14k + 27$.

I am now testing whether or not $(k+1) \in P$, that is whether or not $7\mid 8^{k+1} + 14(k+1) + 27$ is true or not.

I did what I like to call "the good cop bad cop routine" and got the following:

$$7\mid 8^{k+1} + 14(k+1) + 27 +8 -8 \Longrightarrow 7\mid 8(8^{k}-1) + 14k+ 49$$

Hence my question, am I done? Can I say this is true and basically be done with the proof?

Edit: So I made a typo in the problem. It's supposed to read $7\mid 8^{n} - 14n + 27$. I have $+14n$ as the middle term. The exact same logic and steps work though, but instead of ending up with your last term being $49$, it is $21$ (since $8-14+27 = 21$).

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know that $ 7 \, | \, 8(8^k-1)+14k+49$? Where did you use your hypothesis for $n=k$?

Comment: What is "the good cop bad cop routine" (in math)?

Comment: @AnuragA, I know $7\mid (8^{k}-1)$ and so I guess in one sense I don't know that $7 \, | \, 8(8^k-1)+14k+49$. That is what I'm asking. Can I say because 7 divides three of the terms on the right hand side of the | sign, that (k+1) works?

Comment: @Momo, haha, it's just when you do something like $+x-x$ then do some factoring to get a result you want. If you can't get something just from so called "looking at it" you have to do a little trick to get what you want. I was early on in my math education when I was showed this and I guess the name just stuck.

Comment: This is trivial to prove using modular arithmetic, since $8 \equiv 1 \mod 7$.  But of course that doesn't help you learn induction...not that I would care as a teacher.  (I like students to do problems in the simplest way possible.  If I want you to use a particular method, I will give you a problem where that method *is* the simplest approach.)

Comment: $7\mid 8^n + 14n + 27 = 8^n - 1 + 14n + 28$. Since $14$ and $28$ have $7$ as an aliquot divisor, then all you need to prove now is that $7\mid 8^n - 1$, and here, induction is unnecessary. $8^n - 1 = 8^n - 1^n$ and we have that $7 = 8 - 1$. It follows, then, that $8 - 1\mid 8^n - 1^n$ which is clearly valid :)

Answer (score 3):

Step: for $n+1$.

$8^{n+1} +14(n+1) +27=$

$8^n(7+1) +14n  +14 +27=$

$[8^n +14n +27] +7(8^n+2)=$

$=7r + 7(8^n +2) $, $ r \in \mathbb{N}$.

The square bracket is divisible by $7$,
by hypothesis,

the other term is a multiple of $7$,

$\rightarrow$:

the sum is divisible by $7$.

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes you can. Let $f(x) = 8^x +14x+27$. The term $8^k -1=8^k-1^k$ is obviously divisible by seven, as are the other two terms. Since all three terms are divisible by 7, so is their sum. Because you have shown for arbitrary $k$ (given that $7|f(k)$), that the $7|f(k+1)$, you are done!

Comment: Beautiful. Just what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Aside from the instruction to prove it by induction, I don’t see how the statement is suited to induction, as your answer shows. Anyhow, this is the right proof, $+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Use your "good cop bad cop" skills:

\begin{align}
8^{k+1}+14(k+1)+27 &= 8\cdot 8^k+14(k+1)+27\\
&=8(8^k+14k+27-14k-27)+14(k+1)+27\\
&=8(8^k-14k+27)-7\cdot14k+14-7\cdot 27
\end{align}

The first term is divisible by $7$ by the induction hypothesis, for the rest of them it is obvious.